# Or operator not working in firebase rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a realtime database. In rules, doing (a || b) works, but doing (b || a) does not work. I couldn't find the reason. Since my rules are long, I'm putting a small part of it here. actually it was working until today but today it stopped working and i didn't change anything.

Not working :

```
{
    "rules": {
        "allGames": {
            "$gameID": {
                ".read": true
                ".write": "auth != null && ((!data.exists() && 
                (newData.child('players').child('0').child('userID').val().contains(auth.uid) || 
                newData.child('players').child('1').child('userID').val().contains(auth.uid)  || 
                newData.child('players').child('2').child('userID').val().contains(auth.uid)  || 
                newData.child('players').child('3').child('userID').val().contains(auth.uid)) ) ||
                 (!data.exists() && 
                (newData.child('0').child('name').val().contains(auth.uid) || 
                newData.child('1').child('name').val().contains(auth.uid)  || 
                newData.child('2').child('name').val().contains(auth.uid)  || 
                newData.child('3').child('name').val().contains(auth.uid)) ) )"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my json:

```
[
    {
        "durum": "davetYollayan",
        "name": "PzbcSmKziaOcd4PdYNPnIWuG2iH2",
        "score": 0
    },
    {
        "durum": "davetYollayan",
        "name": "efezefebcSmKziaOcd4PdYNPnIWuG2iH2",
        "score": 0
    }
]
```

Screenshot:
[image]

it works when i replace the write code with this. but both codes are the same, I don't understand why it gives an error?

```
".write": "auth != null && ((!data.exists() && 
(newData.child('0').child('name').val().contains(auth.uid) || 
newData.child('1').child('name').val().contains(auth.uid)  || 
newData.child('2').child('name').val().contains(auth.uid)  || 
newData.child('3').child('name').val().contains(auth.uid)) ) || 
(!data.exists() && 
(newData.child('players').child('0').child('userID').val().contains(auth.uid) || 
newData.child('players').child('1').child('userID').val().contains(auth.uid)  || 
newData.child('players').child('2').child('userID').val().contains(auth.uid)  || 
newData.child('players').child('3').child('userID').val().contains(auth.uid)) ))"
```

Comment: can you check using ".write": true does it work?

Comment: yes i tried. It works when write true. It works when I do "newData.child('0').child('name').val() ==auth.uid". but when you do contains, it does not allow writing in the first false state it sees. or although it does not look at other conditions

Comment: I looked through your security rule and there don't seem to be any issues with the syntax, you can raise a free firebase support ticket here : https://firebase.google.com/support